# C program to Reverse a Stack using Recursion

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, linked-list, tail-recursion

I came across the below function to reverse a stack using recursion. Am confused about how it works.

Please help me to understand in a simpler way.

```
void stack_reverse(struct node **head, struct node **head_next)
{
    struct node *temp;

    if (*head_next != NULL)
    {
        temp = (*head_next)->next;
        (*head_next)->next = (*head);
        *head = *head_next;
        *head_next = temp;
        stack_reverse(head, head_next);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really worth figuring out how this works.  It's bad, overly complicated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have commented the code for you, that should help you understand what each line does. If you are still having problems, then I highly recommend you read up on pointers and how they work. Tutorial on pointers [here](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch1x.htm).

```
void stack_reverse(struct node **head, struct node **head_next)
{ 
    // Make a temp node.
    struct node *temp;

    // Check if head_next is not null.
    if (*head_next != NULL)
    {
        // Make temp point to the next element of head_next.
        temp = (*head_next)->next;

        // Make next of head_next point to the head.
        (*head_next)->next = (*head);

        // Make head point to head_next.
        *head = *head_next;

        // Make head_next point to temp.
        *head_next = temp;

        // Call the same function again until you are done.
        stack_reverse(head, head_next);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about to declare `**head_next` in the driver function? I run `**head` by declaring `struct node *Start = NULL` but when I put `struct node *Next = (Start)->next_node;`, there is some kind of error.

Comment: Figured it out. Instead of declaring `**head_next ` as a new node in the driver, I just used the initial node and `->next` it. E.g. `reverseStack(&MyNode, &MyNode->next)`.

Answer (score 2):

Examining how the values of `head` and `head_next` change with each iteration should help understand how the function works.

Start of iteration:

```
*head: NULL
*head_next: a -> b ->  c -> d -> NULL
```

First call to `stack_reverse()`:

```
temp = (*head_next)->next;    // temp:       b -> c -> d -> NULL
(*head_next)->next = (*head); // *head_next: a -> NULL
*head = *head_next;           // *head:      a -> NULL
*head_next = temp;            // *head_next: b -> c -> d -> NULL
```

Second call to `stack_reverse()`:

```
temp = (*head_next)->next;    // temp:       c -> d -> NULL
(*head_next)->next = (*head); // *head_next: b -> a -> NULL
*head = *head_next;           // *head:      b -> a -> NULL
*head_next = temp;            // *head_next: c -> d -> NULL
```

Third call to `stack_reverse()`:

```
temp = (*head_next)->next;    // temp:       d -> NULL
(*head_next)->next = (*head); // *head_next: c -> b -> a -> NULL
*head = *head_next;           // *head:      c -> b -> a -> NULL
*head_next = temp;            // *head_next: d -> NULL
```

Fourth call to `stack_reverse()`:

```
temp = (*head_next)->next;    // temp:       NULL
(*head_next)->next = (*head); // *head_next: d -> c -> b -> a -> NULL
*head = *head_next;           // *head:      d -> c -> b -> a -> NULL
*head_next = temp;            // *head_next: NULL
```

End of recursion.